# Error in alert time

Tags: php, jquery

I have a input field called time_stamp which contain the time. So,when I fetch the time_stamp in jquery and alert it gives a garbage value.This is the code I have tried

```
<input type="text" name"time_stamp" id="time_stamp" value="<?php echo $time ;?>" />
```

and in jquery

```
var time_stamp = $('#time_stamp').val();
alert(time_stamp);
```

Thanks. And correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: use $("#time_stamp").val();

Comment: Why would you ever include a timestamp in an `<input>` field? This is something that the PHP script receiving the form input could easily generate itself. This is just open for the user to spoof...

Comment: Can you give an example of a "garbage value" that it is providing?

Comment: @user3270582 Thank you for your direction. I'm aware how the site works. I'll be certain not to point out your security flaws in the future. Best regards.

Comment: @kyle I have updated the post you can see the error

Comment: Are you sure you were setting `time_stamp` to `$('#time_stamp').val()` before and not `$('#time_stamp').val`? Since the `alert` is alerting a function definition, it seems that you likely left off some parentheses somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly write this

```
alert($('#time_stamp').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you have included jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2) Make sure you place your jQuery code after jQuery core library which is inside another `<script>` tag after the `<script>....</script>` for jQuery library

3) Wrap your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    var time_stamp = $('#time_stamp').val();
    alert(time_stamp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add `$` infront of `('#time_stamp')`

```
var time_stamp = $('#time_stamp').val();
alert(time_stamp);
```

Comment: Sorry. Buddy it's was my typing mistake I already have $ in my code i have edited my post. Please look into it. But still I am getting an error.